# Maven circular dependecy

Tags: maven

1. Project A depends of Project B
2. Project A and B depends of Project C

   A
   --> B
   --> C 0.1
   --> C 0.1

How can I solve all modules will have the same version of C?

Note: I'm owner of all modules

I want declare 1 time dependecy C on pom.xml to avoid multiples declarations

Comment: Please show example pom's ... and also an error output?

Answer (score 0):

You put A, B and C into a multi-module project. Then all three projects have the same version, and you can declare a dependency on C with version `${project.version}`.